# Altering column from INT to BIG INT and fill factor trick

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, fill-factor

I have inherited a script that rebuilds the fill factor sitting at 90 fill factor on the `INT` primary key. It rebuilds it at a fill factor of 50. Then the script drops the index, alters the column to a `BIGINT` and rebuilds the fill factor back to its original 90.

Does that make sense to anyone?  Are they doing this to grow space?  Seems like as soon as they drop the clustered index, the space is a moot point. Thoughts on this?

Comment: Nope, that makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

I have to tell you the only answer I can come up with is "This makes no sense what-so-ever".

From what I can tell they were expanding the table out so there was room for the additional space for the BIGINT.  They then dropped the primary key (presumably the clustered index as well) to avoid some of the time spent increasing the column width then re-created the primary key.

I've never tried this so I can't tell you how long it would take but I can tell you after a great deal of testing which way I went on a similar task.

1. Script and drop all indexes **except** the clustered index.
2. Create a temp table with the correct structure
3. Copy the data from the existing table to the temp table
4. Rename swap
5. Re-create required indexes
6. Drop original table

I wrote about the [logic of it in more detail here](https://sqlstudies.com/2016/07/14/altering-a-column-in-a-large-table-a-case-study/).

Comment: None of it makes any sense. Also, this will cause a rebuild of any non-clustered indexes twice: after dropping the clustered index and after rebuilding it again.

Comment: @RandolphWest Yep. I tend to agree with you. I was just trying to look inside the script writers head :)

Comment: In step 2 do you mean temp table as in #Table or would "working table" be a better choice of words?

Comment: No, more like tmpTable.  Just a new version of the table with the correct structure.